# EmberJS multiple statemanagers/routers

Tags: ember.js

Is it good practice to have multiple statemanagers for the purpose of splitting up multiple outlets that need to maintain separate functionality?

Examples:

- iPad style popover windows (http://metalabdesign.com/images/screenshots/flow-inside.png) - this is a separate controller and view then the current state. It makes sense to me to have a "popover statemanager" - that way the router still stays in its current state when the popover is opened - all the other buttons and actions on the page still work...
- Modal windows, dynamic sidebars, etc...

My thinking is to have a router the controls the main interaction and it simply fires off commands to statemanagers that break up certain "sections" of the current "screen" to isolated parts.

Comment: Did you ever find a good way of handling these multiple statemanagers and outlets?

Comment: Eh, I ended up rationalizing to only have a single state manager / router. I have controllers that observe certain "states" - such as a currentUserController - and my router either interacts with that controller (such as confirming user is logged in when transitioning to a "restricted" route - or the controller tells the router to redirect (such as to a login route).

Comment: OK. I was questioning more the popover style windows you mention - I have a similar question open http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16415686/multiple-routers-in-ember-js

Answer (score 0):

You should have only one router. Then architect your whole application as a series of states interacting between each other through the router. This way your whole application is much more manageable and easier to test.

You might want to look at [This presentation](https://speakerdeck.com/trek/applications-a-series-of-states) for further insight on the subject.