# Multiple routers in ember.js?

Tags: ember.js

In my app I have a requirement for a functional area to open in an overlay such that it sits on top of the current route which could be almost any other route in the app.

This functional area will have it's own routes as it contains at least a master-detail view.

What is the current best practice for dealing with this situation?

Is it possible to have top-level routes that don't tear down the current route/views when entering them? If not and it's necessary to have the ApplicationController (or similar) handle the globally accessible overlay, what's the best way to achieve router-like functionality for that area?

Comment: maybe Ember.Namespace http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Namespace.html is of interest for this kind of architectural task, but not sure tough.

Comment: seeing this question still unanswered makes me think of another possible way to have router like functionality for your messaging area, ember's StateManager: http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.StateManager.html

Comment: Yes, I was thinking I may have to use a separate StateManager. I'm due to revisit this area shortly, will update here if I have any success.

Comment: Did you have any luck with this? I've a similar requirement.

Answer (score 1):

I think you got confused by **open in overlay** requirement and you are trying to solve non-existing problem.

Opening messaging functionality in another page in your app or opening it as overlay on top of the app is just a design thing that should be handled by CSS and existing app router. Just create messaging route, controller, etc.

You didn't say that, but in case you want to boot separate application there, the best approach is to open it in the iframe. New app, new lifecycle, etc. Again, how you display it inside another app is just matter of CSS.

Comment: For this particular feature the requirement is for it to be able to open __on top__ of any other route, so it's not possible to just transition to a route on the existing router. Think of it as a complex modal that has it's own "routes" but not represented in the URL at all. I've removed the "messaging" wording from the question as I think that maybe confusing things.

Comment: @KevinAnsfield Now for me it looks like you need a view - http://emberjs.com/guides/views/ You can insert it in many places (different routes) in your app. It has own controller, can bind properties to controller/template where it was embedded so you can reuse it across your app.

Comment: This part I understand, what I'm having difficulty with is working out how to tie multiple controllers and views together within that one view, how to track state within that view and how to track state of the view being visible/hidden.

Comment: @KevinAnsfield You have one controller for that view. When you do {{view App.MessagerView}} in your template you can bind properties (properties don't need to be primitive, objects and arrays are good too) between your view controller and controllers where view was embedded. Track state you can do using binding as well - your view knows its state - http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.View.html#property_isVisible